# Showing Driver Route between to points in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, routes, google-polyline

I'm doing a simple app using Google Maps v2. All i want is to draw a driver route between two points. I've put polyline but it just draw straight line. The line should track the road. I just don't know how to. Thanks in Advance

This code is just getting the current position, i just set the other latitude and longitude for testing.

here's my code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

GoogleMap googleMap;
GPSTracker gps;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //create class GPS enabled
    gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
    //check if GPS enabled
    if(gps.canGetLocation()){
        try{
            initializeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

        double latitude2 = 13.768000;
        double longitude2 = 122.9768100;

        GoogleMap mMap;

        MarkerOptions Marker2 = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude2,    longitude2)).title("2222");
        googleMap.addMarker(Marker2);
        Marker2.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
        //create Marker
        MarkerOptions Marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("iHatid Maps");
        //add marker
        googleMap.addMarker(Marker);
        // color of marker
        Marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
        //camera motion location
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = CameraPosition.builder().target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(20).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

     } else {
        //can't get location
        //GPS or Network is not enabled
        //ask user to enable GPS/Network in settings
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }
}

private void initializeMap() {
    if(googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        if(googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initializeMap();
    }


}
```

Comment: you need to use some routing API which is not available in google maps. you can use Google Directions API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: @tyczj - do you know some sample code or best tutorial for beginners like me?

Comment: I made a library that does it for you and you can find it here https://github.com/tyczj/MapNavigator but I suggest you try and do it yourself so you know what is happening

Comment: @tyczj -thanks for your library, but as a beginner i find it difficult to understand because there's no comment.

Comment: what do you mean no comment?

Comment: here's my another problem, in my app i can easily get my current location using gps and networks, by using the code UP there. is there a way that my destination can be a marker location from the mysql database (latitude and longitude)

Comment: sure just pull the lat/lng from you database and use that for the marker location

Comment: @tyczj how about this one, is there a way to show multiple location to pin in google maps, the latitude and longitude from the database and show it to google maps in android....=)

Answer (score 2):

Use the path information provided by Google in `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json...`.

Just look at this link [here.](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=12.957991900000000000,77.703563300000040000&destination=12.918155800000000000,77.647169299999970000&sensor=false)

You can find all information between two geopoints, like distance(on road), duration with both in walk and driving mode.

You just have to give two inputs(origin and destination lat lon) and parse the json provided there.

For coding help you can follow this [tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-distance-and-travel-time-duration-between-two-locations-in-google-map-android-api-v2/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the google direction API by just passing the two points as arguments and the google web service will return the route in JSON, then you can parse the data, extract the different points and finally show the route.

For further informations, check the [google direction API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, you mean i can make a new function and get the latitude, longitude, latitude2 and longitude2 in my code?

Comment: I was actually talking about the next step; once you got the two points (source, destination), you can use the Google Direction API to get the route between them.